# trigger page zoom event with javascript

Tags: javascript, events, scroll, zooming, mouse

I am building Cocos Creator game, which has a canvas. I noticed if player click the game canvas he **can** **not** zoom the page using Ctrl + mouse scroll.

If he click the web page he can zoom with Ctrl + mouse scroll as usual.

I found a way to detect mouse scroll within cocos game.

What I wanted to do is to trigger a Ctrl + mouse scroll event in the web page.

I can call a java-script function in the web-page from the cocos creator game.

But I don't know how to fire such event though.

Can anyone provide some assistance on this?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like below.

```
var scale = 'scale(2)'; // 2x
document.body.style.transform = scale;
```

Since you can capture mouse scroll, you can increase/decrease the amount you want to scale within the event capture and trigger a transform as mentioned above.

**Edit** - CSS related solution

```
var zoom = function() {
   zoomLevel += 0.1;
   $('body').css({ zoom: zoomLevel, '-moz-transform': 'scale(' + zoomLevel + ')' });
}
```

Using a similar function you can zoom out as well.

Comment: your method does change zoom level of the page. The problem I have is when you do Ctrl + mouse zoom it happens independently to this zoom. If I change the zoom to 2. Mouse scroll zoom  is still 100%. What I would like to do is fire the Ctrl + move scroll event into the web page.

Comment: Try the css related solution and see. Im not sure though.